# AngularJS 1.5.8 : Controller & Scope

Tags: angularjs, controller

ok I've got some problem with the scope controller I've tried many different things but it doesn't work with the version from Angular that I've declared (1.5.8)

so here is my code html :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">



<input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
<select ng-model="order">
    <option value="username">Organiser par nom</option>
    <option value="content">Organiser par content</option>
</select>


<div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments |filter:{content: query} |orderBy:">
        <p>
                <strong>{{comment.username}}</strong><br>
                {{comment.content}}
        </p>

    </div>  
</div>
```

and this is my java Script:

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]); 
myApp.controller('CommentsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [ 
{ 
"username": "Goodman", 
"city": "Bonanza", 
"email": "goodmanalston@helixo.com", 
"content": "naborum ut. Nisi in ex consequat quis sitet exercitation." 
}, 
{ 
"username": "Holder", 
"city": "Lloyd", 
"email": "holderalston@helixo.com", 
"content": "naborum ut. Nisi in exunt magna in et exercitation." 
} 
]; 
}]);
</script>
```

It cannot display the scope any ideas ?

Comment: put your input tag inside your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `<input type="text" ng-model="query"/>` into `<div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">`

Answer (score 0):

[Here is your working code](http://jsfiddle.net/y7r1xe0t/303/).

As Tilekbekov Yrysbek mentioned, you have to move your code and also add your orderBy parameter. So final HTML code will be

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
<select ng-model="order">
    <option value="username">Organiser par nom</option>
    <option value="content">Organiser par content</option>
</select>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments |filter:{content: query} |orderBy:order">
        <p>
                <strong>{{comment.username}}</strong><br>
                {{comment.content}}
        </p>

    </div>  
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**OrderBy** Should not be empty.
Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments |filter:{content: query} |orderBy:order">
```